Using Kirchoff's Laws instead of The Superposition Theorem?
So my textbook introduced The Superposition Theorem, and, to me, applying a combination of Kirchoff's Current and Voltage Laws seems to simplify the process for solving for the current or voltage of interest in a resistor or other component, keeping in mind the algebraic signs of the voltage sources, currents, etc.  Solving a system of equations is not a problem for me with the calculator that I have, so besides that, what are the downsides of bypassing The Superposition Theorem by using a combination of Kirchoff's Laws? And is there any situation in which this would not be possible?

The superposition theorem is just another way of thinking about things. I almost never care to use it for the reason you mention.

Solving multiple simultaneous equations using nodal or loop equations is fine for getting numerical results, but it's very difficult to get insight into how to design a circuit by that means.  An advantage of the superposition principle is that the resulting equations often can give a great deal of insight into what to change to get a desired result.  You can investigate this idea in the writings of the late Dr. R. David Middlebrook.

Sometimes you need a screwdriver. Sometimes you need a wrench. Sometimes when you need a screwdriver a wrench will work but badly.
It is best to have multiple tools available.

Anyway you could be more specific?

The superposition theorem is used to simplify the circuit by using one or more voltage or current source at time. If the currents and voltages can be found out without superposition with KVL and KCL, then there is no point in using superposition. Sometimes, isolating each energy source and using one energy source at a time is handy and may be relevant just to simplify the circuit analysis.

I think, the most simple method for finding the gain of inverting opamp stage (opamp ideal) is to use superposition: Vn=Vn1+Vn2=VinR2/(R1+R2)+VoutR1/(R1+R2)=0

I had seen that in op amps and BJT circuits , superposition theorem is used to simplify circuit analysis.
